# php foreach radio button percentage

Tags: php, foreach, radio-button, percentage

Hello there I have a quiz in radio button and there are three buttons and two teams on either side of radio button.

First radio button means team 1 wins second radio button means its a draw third radio button means team 2 wins.

Now I am saving that in database with comma separated values for each users like if there are four questions and choose first option for every game his result would look like 1,1,1,1.

now if two users played this game the array will look like.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [prediction] => 1,1,1,1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [prediction] => 1,2,1,2
        )

)
```

Now I want to show percentage based on user prediction like both user choose
1 for first answer so first answer should show 100% and second one will show 50%.

Now I have multiple radio button they are in a foreach loop and that user prediction loop is diifferent.

If I could check no of keys matching like for 0 index both are one so the sum would be 2 and count of array user prediction will be 2 because two user played it so far so I would 2/2*100=100%.

This is really bugging me for days could not get my head around it please help guys if you can Thanks.

This is my foreach loop for radio button
it will be as many games added by admin
foreach($games[0] as $usergames){ ?>
   type="radio" name="" value="1" required>
       class="radio_button" type="radio" id="" name="" value="2">
       class="radio_button" type="radio" name="" value="3">

if there are two games it would look like 
Sweden     1 2 3 Norway
Australia  1 2 3 Germany
so the user will choose if swedes wins or if its a draw or norway wins
same goes for Australia and Germany
and in the database it is saved with user id,prediction,and games id
now in the database there are two entries for games id=4 i.e. our game above
so the user count would be 2.
and suppose there prediction will be 1,1 2,1
first user says Sweden and Australia wins
second user says its a draw and Australia wins
So the percentage of user prediction for sweden wins would be 50% draw would be 50%
and percentage for Australia wins is 50% and draw would be 50%
now if third user made prediction on the same game and choose norway wins the percentage of all would be 33%

Comment: Maybe if you show the code we will understand better what on earth you are talking about

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have understood you. So try this, if index of array matches the same questions for both users.

```
$percentages = [];
foreach ($predictionUser1 as $ix => $answer) {
    $percentages[$ix] = ($answer != $predictionUser2[$ix]) ? 50% : 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Well oliver if a third user choose different option it would be 33%
and it would vary according to user prediction if four user played and 3 of them chooses first option than percentage for first option would be 75%.
and that percentage is calculated for all option but sum of  all of them would be 100%

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/jha2dq3w9/
In the image I have user prediction and radio buttons Based on that Sweden

Comment: based on the image Sweden

Comment: Sweden vs Norway would be 1-100% x-0% 2-0%

Comment: Could you explain the prediction-string a litte bit more. I have understand now, that the integers of your example (1,2,1,2) represents the values of the radio-inputs. But what does the 3th and 4th integer means, if you save each user in a row and there are only 2 possible answers (2 games)?

Comment: No oliver in the example there are four games so four comma sap rated